# Scikit RFECV not working with float step

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, feature-selection, rfe

I'm using scikit's recursive feature elimination to get rid of some features.

When using the straight up [RFE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html), I can set the step as a float, meaning that (for instance) 10% of the features should be eliminated at each step. It works well.

When switching to [RFECV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html), this seems to not work.

Code sample (works fine with *RFE* and fails with *RFECV*):

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV

selector = RFECV(model_classifier, step=0.1, cv=3, 
                 scoring='roc_auc', verbose=10, n_jobs=-1)

selector.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Symptoms:

- Process goes on forever without ending.
- No cores seem to activate.
- Stdout prints: `... lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py:198: DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  support_[features[ranks][:threshold]] = False`
- Stdout also prints:
  `Fitting estimator with 177 features.
  Fitting estimator with 177 features.
  Fitting estimator with 177 features.
  Fitting estimator with 124 features.
  Fitting estimator with 124 features.
  Fitting estimator with 71 features.
  Fitting estimator with 71 features.
  Fitting estimator with 124 features.
  Fitting estimator with 18 features.
  Fitting estimator with 18 features.
  Fitting estimator with 71 features.
  Fitting estimator with 18 features.`
  (but nothing actually happens)
- Works fine with integer step

Comment: Quite weird indeed ... I am reading the source code but I can't spot where you problem comes from because when the argument step is not an integer, the code transforms it into an integer (cf **line 146**)

**link** : https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/412996f/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py#L263

Comment: Apparently it is a [known bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7467), reported last week. I've mentioned this on their GitHub's issues page too.